# Increase length of \hline

Tags: tables

I want to increase the length of horizontal lines, \hline, but unsure of how.

Here is my current table:

[image]

But I want all 3 horizontal lines to be longer on the right hand side, as shown here:

[image]

Here is my code for my current table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % Times font for text
\usepackage{newtxmath} % Times font for math
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular} {lllll}
\hline 
\hline 
Phase \hspace{0.17cm} & Treatment Effect \hspace{0.17cm} & Crowding Out \hspace{0.17cm} & Grant Ratio \hspace{0.17cm} & Grant Ratio Diff \\
\hline 
I-II & 9.71\% & 1.36\% & 10.41\% & 0.7 \\
III & 4.47\% & -1.67\% & 1.74\% & 4.47 \\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why? The goal is fit the margins? Or just have a empt right space in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`@{\hspace{3cm}}` adds an extra 3 centimeters of space after the last column. This effectively extends the horizontal lines (`\hline`) to the right.
You can adjust the 3cm to the desired length.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % Times font for text
\usepackage{newtxmath} % Times font for math
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular} {lllll@{\hspace{3cm}}} % Add extra horizontal space after the last column
\hline 
\hline 
Phase \hspace{0.17cm} & Treatment Effect \hspace{0.17cm} & Crowding Out \hspace{0.17cm} & Grant Ratio \hspace{0.17cm} & Grant Ratio Diff \\
\hline 
I-II & 9.71\% & 1.36\% & 10.41\% & 0.7 \\
III & 4.47\% & -1.67\% & 1.74\% & 4.47 \\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the purpose would be.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % Times font for text
\usepackage{newtxmath} % Times font for math
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  l
  *{4}{>{$}c<{$}}
  X
}
\hline\noalign{\vspace{2pt}}
\cline{1-5}
Phase&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Treatment Effect} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Crowding Out} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Grant Ratio} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Grant Ratio Diff} &
\hspace*{\fill}\\
\hline 
I-II & 9.71\% & 1.36\% & 10.41\% & 0.7 &\\
III & 4.47\% & -1.67\% & 1.74\% & 4.47 &\\
\hline
\end{tabularx} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's how I would typeset it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % Times font for text
\usepackage{newtxmath} % Times font for math
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=1.2\%]
  S[table-format=-1.2\%]
  S[table-format=2.2\%]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Phase&
{Treatment Effect} &
{Crowding Out} &
{Grant Ratio} &
{Grant Ratio Diff} \\
\midrule
I-II & 9.71\% & 1.36\% & 10.41\% & 0.7 \\
III & 4.47\% & -1.67\% & 1.74\% & 4.47 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*} 

\end{document}
```

[image]